# Hibernate - Hello World - Unknown Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Java Code:

```
  package hello;

  import org.hibernate.Session;
  import org.hibernate.Transaction;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Message {
 private Long id;
 private String text;
 private Message nextMessage;

 private Message() {}

 public Message(String text) {
  this.text = text;
 }

 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 private void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getText() {
  return text;
 }

 public void setText(String text) {
  this.text = text;
 }

 public Message getNextMessage() {
  return nextMessage;
  }

 public void setNextMessage(Message nextMessage) {
  this.nextMessage = nextMessage;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    System.out.println("Conf Loaded Successfully");
    Session session = conf.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Message message = new Message("Hello World");
    session.save(message);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("Written to DB successfully");
 }

}
```

Auto generated Hibernate Configuration and XML files with Hibernate 4.0.1

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
       <!-- Generated Dec 5, 2015 9:20:05 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
      <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="hello.Message" table="MESSAGE">
          <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
           <column name="ID" />
           <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="text" type="java.lang.String">
         <column name="TEXT" />
        </property>
        <one-to-one name="nextMessage" class="hello.Message"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate 4.0.1 is my eclipse plugin. But I see something 3 in xmlns. Is it the problem?

Project structure

```
    hibernateFirst
          src/main/java
             hello
               Message
          src/main/resources
             hello
               Message.hbm.xml
          hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Error:

```
      Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: hello.Message
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1520)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:679)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:666)
at hello.Message.main(Message.java:49)
```

Please help me to solve.

I just tried by changing hello/Message in the mapping. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The declared class name in your xml config is just "Message", no need for "hello"

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm for a simple example

The same is true in the one-to-one mapping too.